# How to convert String to ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, string, arraylist

Let's say I have this String -

```
string = "AEIOU";
```

and I wanted to convert it to an `ArrayList<String>`, where each character is it's own individual `String` within the `ArrayList<String>`

```
[A, E, I, O, U]
```

EDIT: I do NOT want to convert to `ArrayList<Character>` (yes, that's very straightforward and I do pay attention in class), but I DO want to convert to an `ArrayList<String>`.

How would I do that?

Comment: Another Homework Question?

Comment: Do you know how to get a single `char` from a String?

Comment: I don't want to convert it to a Character ArrayList (I know how to do that easily), but rather a String ArrayList. None of the solutions so far convert to an ArrayList<String>, rather an ArrayList<Character>.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

transform the `String` into a `char` array,

```
char[] cArray = "AEIOU".toCharArray();
```

and while you iterate over the array, transform each `char` into a `String`, and then add it to the list,

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(cArray.length);

for(char c : cArray){
    list.add(String.valueOf(c));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop and use `String.charAt(i)`, to build the new list.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using the split method and setting the delimiter as an empty string like this:

`ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(string.split("")));`

Answer (score 1):

First you have to define the arrayList and then iterate over the string and create a variable to hold the char at each point within the string. then you just use the add command. You will have to import the arraylist utility though.

```
String string = "AEIOU";
ArrayList<char> arrayList = new ArrayList<char>();

for (int i = 0; i < string.length; i++)
{
  char c = string.charAt(i);
  arrayList.add(c);
}
```

The import statement looks like : import java.util.ArrayList;

To set it as a string arrayList all you have to do is convert the char variables we gave you and convert it back to a string then add it: (And import the above statement)

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
String string = "AEIOU"

for (int i = 0; i < string.length; i++)
{
  char c = string.charAt(i);
  String answer = Character.toString(c);
  arrayList.add(answer);
}
```

Comment: Pretty straight forward to do it as a string array too. All you do is convert the char variables back into a string.

Comment: Thank you for not being condescending like some other members. I appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

Since everyone is into doing homework this evening ...

```
String myString = "AEIOU";
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(myString.length());
for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
    myList.add(String.valueOf(myString.charAt(i)));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For a single line answer use the following code :

```
    Arrays.asList(string .toCharArray());
```

Comment: Nope, it returns List<char[]>

Answer (score -1):

Kotlin approach:

```
fun String.toArrayList(): ArrayList<String> {
    return ArrayList(this.split("").drop(1).dropLast(1))
}

var letterArray = "abcd".toArrayList()
print(letterArray) // arrayListOf("a", "b", "c", "d")
```